# Load different data in the same TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

In my app I have on main form a `tc_main` as `TTabControl` with 4 tabs and a `vt_main` as `TVirtualStringTree` stays on it. Depends by the tab selected `vt_main` may had different header and data inside. For each tab I define a different data handler.

```
Tvt_main = record
  column: array of String;
end;

Pvt_tab_equip = ^Tvt_main;
Pvt_tab_insp = ^Tvt_main;
Pvt_tab_certif = ^Tvt_main;
Pvt_tab_doc = ^Tvt_main;

const
  sz_vt_main = SizeOf(Tvt_main);
```

Now the question is how can I switch between tabs and refresh `vt_main` view by maintaining the data from handlers, without to reload the data's from sql.

In this moment when I try to update the header configuration I get Access Violation.

I will put some code. I hope you get the point.

```
procedure Tform_main.tc_mainChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //draw/redraw `vt_main header` each time TabIndex is changed.
  draw_vt_main_header;

  //if content not loaded, then load data from sql.
  if not vt_loaded[tc_main.TabIndex] then draw_vt_main;

  //search for some text
  search;
end;
```

and here is the draw/redraw VT header procedure

```
procedure Tform_main.draw_vt_main_header;
var
  tab_index, i: Word;
begin
  tab_index:= tc_main.TabIndex;

  vt_main.Header.SortColumn:= -1;
  vt_main.Header.Columns.Clear;

  if Length(vt_header[tab_index].column) > 0 then
    for i := 0 to High(vt_header[tab_index].column) do
      if vt_header[tab_index].column[i].position >= 0 then
        with vt_main.Header.Columns.Add do
          begin
            Text:= vt_header[tab_index].column[i].caption;
            Width:= vt_header[tab_index].column[i].width;
            Position:= vt_header[tab_index].column[i].position;

            if vt_header[tab_index].column[i].visible then
              Options:= Options + [coVisible]
            else
              Options:= Options - [coVisible];

            CaptionAlignment:= taCenter;
            Alignment:= vt_header[tab_index].column[i].alignement;
          end;
end;
```

Comment: Ask yourself why you are putting the data into the control? Do it the virtual way and the way forward is trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand. Please be more explicit.

Comment: Store the data in a separate data structure. Present it using the virtual paradigm? Read the VTV documentation if that means nothing.

Comment: Your suggestion is to create a variable and store all the data and then each time the tab is changed to assign the proper ones to the VT handler (pointer)?

Comment: Essentially that's it.

Comment: I will do like so. Thank you! Transpose your comment as an answer and I will make it valid.

Comment: As with everything, even here you have at least two options. Either you will use those internal data pointers (and bind them to your data collection items), or you won't use them (in case of simple grid view with no tree structure you can simply work with the node index values; and this option is what might be taken as a real virtual mode, because in this case there is no binding between the control and data; the control does not know anything about the data).